# Searchview shows wrong result on Recyclerview with viewpager

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer, searchview

I have  viewpager which has two fragments

in one of my fragments,I use searchview for recyclerview in that fragment.

This is the recyclerview adapter : (with search filter)

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyviewHolder> implements Filterable {
    ListItemsBinding itembind;
    Context co;
    List<Items> mylist;
    List<Items> copy;

    public CustomAdapter(List<Items> mylist, Context co) {
        this.mylist = mylist;
        copy=new ArrayList<>(mylist);
        this.co = co;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CustomAdapter.MyviewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(co);
        itembind= ListItemsBinding.inflate(inflater,parent,false);
        return new MyviewHolder(itembind);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CustomAdapter.MyviewHolder holder, int position) {
        Items item = mylist.get(position);
        itembind.text.setText(item.getName());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mylist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return exampleFilter;
    }


    private final Filter exampleFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            List<Items> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                filteredList.addAll(copy);
            } else {
                String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

                for (Items item : copy) {
                    if (item.getName().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                        filteredList.add(item);
                    }
                }
            }

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = filteredList;

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            mylist.clear();
            mylist.addAll((List) results.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    public class MyviewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {


        public MyviewHolder(ListItemsBinding itembind) {
            super(itembind.getRoot());

            itembind.const1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(co,""+mylist.get(getAdapterPosition()).getName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });






        }
    }
}
```

Fragment2.java  (In this fragment I've implemented onCreateOptionsMenu) :

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment implements {
   
    CustomAdapter adaptive;
    List<Items> mylist;
    Fragment2Binding filesbinding;


 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        filesbinding= FragmentVoiceRecordFilesBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false);
        return filesbinding.getRoot();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
       

setdata();
recycle();


}

 public void recycle() {

//implementing recyclerview

                filesbinding.recycle.setHasFixedSize(true);
                RecyclerView.LayoutManager layout = new 
               LinearLayoutManager(context);
                filesbinding.recycle.setLayoutManager(layout);
                filesbinding.recycle.scheduleLayoutAnimation();
                adaptive= new CustomAdapter(mylist,context);
                filesbinding.recycle.setAdapter(adaptive);


}

public void setdata() {
            mylist=new ArrayList<>();
            mylist.add(new Items("1"));
            mylist.add(new Items("2"));
            mylist.add(new Items("3"));
            mylist.add(new Items("4"));
        }

@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.actionSearch);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                 return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                adaptive.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    }


}
```

searchmenu.xml :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">



    <!-- item for our search view with its id -->
    <item
        android:id="@+id/actionSearch"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
        android:title="Search"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />


</menu>
```

The problem is when I click search icon on toolbar and type something, filter works

but the result inside recyclerview has diffrent name. but when I click on it  and

the toast appears, the correct name is on toast, in recyclerview it is something else.

[Here is a picture of what is happenning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDzmD.png)

Answer (score 1):

I could fix my problem. The problem was in my recyclerview adapter.

I should have implemented view binding in recyclerview like this :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62255625/17948179

Here is the updated CustomAdapter :

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyviewHolder> implements Filterable {
    Context co;
    List<Items> mylist;
    List<Items> copy;

    public CustomAdapter(List<Items> mylist, Context co) {
        this.mylist = mylist;
        copy=new ArrayList<>(mylist);
        this.co = co;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CustomAdapter.MyviewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MyviewHolder(ListItemsBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(co),parent,false));
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CustomAdapter.MyviewHolder holder, int position) {
        Items item = mylist.get(position);
        holder.itembind.text.setText(item.getName());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mylist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return exampleFilter;
    }


    private final Filter exampleFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            List<Items> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                filteredList.addAll(copy);
            } else {
                String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

                for (Items item : copy) {
                    if (item.getName().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                        filteredList.add(item);
                    }
                }
            }

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = filteredList;

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            mylist.clear();
            mylist.addAll((List) results.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };

    public class MyviewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private ListItemsBinding itembind;

        public MyviewHolder(ListItemsBinding itembind) {
            super(itembind.getRoot());
            this.itembind=itembind;


            itembind.const1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(co,""+mylist.get(getAdapterPosition()).getName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });






        }
    }
}
```

I hope this will help somebody in the future.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).